# change cell color with conditional format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wanna ask about Ms. excel. maybe it will look so basic for someone who always work with excel. so thank you for anyone who help me with this.
I have sheet1 and sheet2. so i want to make cell in column A sheet 1, which have same data exist in column A sheet2 to change color automatically.

I don't know how to make it work so I made column helper in column c sheet1 with this formula
`=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(a2;sheet2!$A$2:$A$1000;)))`
and get true if the data exist in sheet2. and then I drag that formula so all column c have this formula.
I thinking using conditional formatting, so I block column A in sheet 1, and make conditional formatting with formula
=C:C= "TRUE"

but this not work. i really a newbie and only study by myself from internet, but i dunno how to search to solve this problem.
any help or advice for this problem?
thank you so much before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the formula that returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` directly into the conditional formatting rule.

You should define it on cell `A2` first, then change the 'Applies to' range to be all the rows you want to test. If you can, I recommend you try to avoid using references like `C:C`.

So, supposing you want to test the data in cells `A2:A10` on sheet1, then your rule would look something like this:

[image]

Note that my locale uses comma as parameter separator and not semi-colon, so you should adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following formula in CF rule.

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A:$A,"*"&$A1&"*")>0
```

[image]